# Press Event in GtkToolButton

Tags: c, events, gtk3

I have a toolbar and some toolbuttons in Gtk3+, but instead of clicking, I would like to track the press event. I tried:

```
priv->toolbar  = gtk_toolbar_new();
priv->btn_right= GTK_WIDGET(gtk_tool_button_new(NULL,NULL));
gtk_widget_add_events(priv->btn_right, GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK);
g_signal_connect(priv->btn_right,  "button-press-event",
                 G_CALLBACK(at_btn_right_pressed),self); 
gtk_toolbar_insert(GTK_TOOLBAR(priv->toolbar),
                   GTK_TOOL_ITEM(priv->btn_right),
                   6);
```

But it doesn't work. If I replace `button-press-event` for `click`, it works for click event. `at_btn_right_pressed(GtkWidget*, GdkEvent*, gpointer)` is a common handler for these events.

**UPDATE**:
I'm building an image viewer, with four toolbar "buttons" (left, up, top, bottom). When the user presses the "button" with the mouse, the image is translated to the chosen direction. The `clicked` signal is not a good solution because the user needs to click many times to translate the image, but just one press event + one release one to accomplish the same task.
A [MWE](https://gist.github.com/anderflash/b9cffe559f3981e3fc63e9e0d4eb63ac) in Gist

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is it doesn't reach the callback. I put breakpoints, but the debugging process does not stop there, even though I replace all callback content for just a printf+return. I made an [MWE](https://gist.github.com/anderflash/b9cffe559f3981e3fc63e9e0d4eb63ac)

Comment: Don't worry. Maybe it's a Gtk+ design decision. So I can reconsider redesigning the interface for not using GtkToolbar. At the moment, I added keyboard shortcuts to do the translation.

Comment: A little inspection on the [GtkToolButton source code](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/master/gtk/gtktoolbutton.c) reveals that GtkToolButton is just a container which has a GtkButton child, and we don't have access to it. Just the `click` event of the button is propagated to the toolbutton. I think this encapsulation loses flexibility to several applications. The GtkToolButton could propagate other GtkButton events, or add an accessor to the button.

Comment: That explains it. I kept thinking all along it was a `GtkButton` for some reason. Maybe you could use some sort of panel below your image for control panel like most image viewers do. Also, you could post your answer to your main question (that's generally what SO recommends if you solved your problem) and explain how you will work around this limitation.

Answer (score -1):

There doesn't seem to be an easy way to disable the default 'clicked' handler. Apparently, that click handler is stealing the 'pressed' event from the user. If you are fast enough, you can see this happening (At least that's my explanation of it). When a button is clicked, it waits for a couple of 100's of milliseconds to check if another click happens (the double click event). During that time, Press events *do* get through. Test it running the following program, click repeatedly (and fast) on the button:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
#  test_toolbar_press.py
#  
#  Copyright 2016 John Coppens <john@jcoppens.com>
#  
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
#  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#  
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#  
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
#  Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston,
#  MA 02110-1301, USA.
#  
#  


from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

class MyToolbar(Gtk.Toolbar):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyToolbar, self).__init__()

        btn = Gtk.ToolButton(None, None)
        btn.connect("button-press-event", self.btn_pressed)
        btn.connect_after("clicked", self.btn_clicked)

        self.insert(btn, 0)

    def btn_pressed(self, wdg, event):
        print("Button pressed")

    def btn_clicked(self, wdg):
        print("Button clicked")

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.connect("destroy", lambda x: Gtk.main_quit())
        self.set_size_request(200, 50)

        tbar = MyToolbar()
        self.add(tbar)

        self.show_all()

    def run(self):
        Gtk.main()


def main(args):
    mainwdw = MainWindow()
    mainwdw.run()

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Clicking slow shows the normal 'Clicks', faster also shows the 'Presses':

[image: Output of the program]

I suggest the following solution - though it's not a toolbar, you can do a variation of this to fit your design:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
#  test_toolbar_press.py
#  
#  Copyright 2016 John Coppens <john@jcoppens.com>
#  
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
#  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#  
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#  
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
#  Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston,
#  MA 02110-1301, USA.
#  
#  


from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

class MyNavbar(Gtk.Grid):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyNavbar, self).__init__()

        for dir, x, y in (("N", 1, 0), ("E", 2, 1), ("S", 1, 2), ("W", 0, 1)):
            btn = Gtk.Button(dir, None)
            btn.connect("button-press-event", self.btn_pressed, dir)
            btn.connect("button-release-event", self.btn_released, dir)
            self.attach(btn, x, y, 1, 1)

    def btn_pressed(self, wdg, event, data):
        print("Button pressed %s" % data)

    def btn_released(self, wdg, event, data):
        print("Button released %s" % data)

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.connect("destroy", lambda x: Gtk.main_quit())
        self.set_size_request(200, 50)

        tbar = MyNavbar()
        self.add(tbar)

        self.show_all()

    def run(self):
        Gtk.main()


def main(args):
    mainwdw = MainWindow()
    mainwdw.run()

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

This is the result:

[image] and this is the program output:

```
Button pressed N
Button released N
Button pressed E
Button released E
Button pressed S
Button released S
Button pressed W
Button released W
```

My apologies for doing the examples in Python. However, it shouldn't be too difficult to translate the basic Gtk functions into C.

Comment: if it `shouldn't be too difficult to translate the basic Gtk functions into C.`  Then why don't you do it, instead of posting a python response to a c question?